# the process between a frontend, backend and cloud database

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm having a hard time finding information on simple straight forward process. I keep getting forwarded things like the "google cloud engine" and such.

I am attempting to start a new project to expand my knowledge. Previously, I developed a localhost web app which included; working frontend with react, express backend (REST api) and mongo database. I understood the concepts effectively of rest calls, state management and authentications and such.

The new setup is flutter, nodeJS (express), and firebase.

Looking at quick tutorials I have a simple flutter app working with a http post for a user sign up. Makes sense.

Normally in nodeJS, I'd have a route it hits e.g. `router.post('/users', function (req, res, next) ...` and then I'd have a model scheme to and if everything is correct it would post.

Exploring the relationship with firebase and nodeJS I'm slightly overwhelmed on how this works. I thought it would be something simple as an authentication key (which, btw I have sorted out with firebase-admin) and then proceed on my merry way with my models and routes/services.

Are the models defined within firebase, and my node just confirms the requests and talks through the firebase API? I haven't been able to locate any *simple* resources for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't say which product within Firebase you're using ([Firebase is a suite of products](https://blog.usejournal.com/what-is-firebase-the-complete-story-abridged-bcc730c5f2c0), not just one thing), I'm going to assume you mean Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore.  They are both schemaless NoSQL databases -- they don't impose any structure on the data you put into them.  There's no model, there's no validation.  That's all stuff you have to do on your own, if you want.  Or not, if you want flexibility.

Comment: mind blown. I guess that makes sense, and yes the realtime db/firestore.